# Using GeoServer GetLegendGraphic and point symbolizer size 1

Tags: wms, getlegendgraphic

I'm currently facing an issue with the GeoServer GetLegendGraphic operation when using a point symbolizer with a size of 1. The problem is that when I request a legend graphic with this small point size, the resulting preview appears broken or distorted. However, when I increase the size to 2 or larger, the legend graphic is displayed correctly.

I have created a style on GeoServer with a rule that includes a point symbolizer and specified a size of 1

```
      <se:Rule>
      <se:Name>PointSize</se:Name>
      <se:Description>
        <se:Title>PointSize</se:Title>
      </se:Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" />
      <se:PointSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/pixel">
        <se:Graphic>
          <se:Mark>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
            <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
          </se:Mark>
          <se:Size>1</se:Size>
          <se:Displacement>
            <se:DisplacementX>0</se:DisplacementX>
            <se:DisplacementY>0</se:DisplacementY>
          </se:Displacement>
        </se:Graphic>
      </se:PointSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
```

When I make a GetLegendGraphic request with the appropriate parameters, the preview image does not accurately represent the symbolizer at this size.

For comparing:

Preview image when size = 1 : [image: size of point = 1]

Preview image when size = 2 : [image: size of point = 2]

My request:
http://somehost.com/geoserver/ows?service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&format=image/png&width=32&height=32&layer=layerworkspace:layerName&namespace=layerworkspace&rule=PointSize

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or have any insights into why this might be happening?